# typescript variable declaration get error

Tags: typescript

When i declare a variable it doesn't show any error (red mark underline). But when i run the code, i got error.

Below is the code:

```
var user: string = "Jane User";
console.log(user);
```

Below is the error i got when compiled/running this file:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var user:string = "Jane User";
                                                                  ^                          SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i tried it here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html , I got no such error

Comment: how are you compiling the code?

Comment: you probably did not compile it, types can only exist in ts file, do : create file myprog.ts, tsc myprog.ts, node myprog.js

Comment: i compiled through : tsc filename.ts

Comment: and then run using node filename.ts

Comment: you shouldn't run the ts code... run the js code instead. :)

Comment: It's working now.. Thanks AnatolyStrashkevich, toskv.